# Inserting List<T>.Contains elements in a SQL database

Tags: c#

I want to compare names in 2 lists of names that i have fetched from the database comparing the names character by character which returns a percentage then insert the records in the database(names and the percentage) Below is what i have achieved so far.

Am fetching the names from the 2 tables and storing then in 2 lists.

```
var ListOfAM = new List<ZapData>();
var ListOfAML = new List<AmlData>();
```

Am Looping through the 2 lists comparing the string elements character by character (I have that function).

```
foreach (var am in ListOfAM)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < ListOfAML.Count(); i++)
      {
         string compare = clsCompare.percentage(am.firstName, ListOfAML[i].firstName).ToString();//the function that compares the 2 strings and returns a percentage of type double.  

         //Inserting the list elements to the database.                                               
         using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(clsOracleTasks.GetDatabaseServerConfigs()))
         {
             if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
             {                                                            
                 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO AML_PERCENTAGE_TEST ( FIRST_NAME, SECOND_NAME, LAST_NAME, PERCENTAGE ) VALUES (@FIRST_NAME, @SECOND_NAME, @LAST_NAME, '100')");
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                 cmd.Connection = conn; 
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@FIRST_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ListOfAML[i].firstName;
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@SECOND_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ListOfAML[i].secondName;
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@LAST_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ListOfAML[i].lastName;     

                 conn.Open();
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
           }
      }
  }
```

When inserting to the database, it throws an exception

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

How can i fix this at my insert?

Comment: Can you give your table schema ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi 

CREATE TABLE AML_PERCENTAGE_TEST
(
  FIRST_NAME   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)                NOT NULL,
  SECOND_NAME  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)                NOT NULL,
  LAST_NAME    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)                NOT NULL,
  PERCENTAGE   NUMBER(10)                       NOT NULL
)